# PowerShell - Copy file to USB by using serial number

Tags: powershell

I have a quite complicated CMD/Batch script I want to move to PowerShell, but have not found a way to access the USB-device by using the device ID. I have learned device ID are only following the USB stick on the particular machine, if moved to another machine a new device ID will be generated.

So using device serial number are preferred, as it follows the USB device.

This is what I have today, a script that get the drive-letter from device id and run Robocopy.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
call :getDriveLetter "\\?\Volume{*the-guid-masked*}\"

:endlocal
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:getDriveLetter
set "_volumeID=%~1"
set "_DriveLetter="
for /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%G in ('
wmic volume where "DeviceID='%_volumeID:\=\\%'" get DriveLetter /value
') do for /F %%g in ("%%~H") do set "_%%~G=%%~g"
call :doSomething
goto :eof

:doSomething
>> "D:\Logs\USB_Synk_%date%.log" (
    if defined _DriveLetter (
        robocopy "E:\Backup" "%_DriveLetter%\Backup" /MIR
    ) else (
        echo %_volumeID% DriveLetter unknown
        exit /b 999
    )
)
goto :eof
```

Please give advice me and point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function below to probe the system for a USB drive with a certain serial number:

```
function Get-UsbDriveLetter {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [string]$SerialNumber
    )

    $wmiQuery1 = 'ASSOCIATORS OF {{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="{0}"}} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition'
    $wmiQuery2 = 'ASSOCIATORS OF {{Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="{0}"}} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition'
    # for PowerShell < 3.0 use Get-WmiObject instead of Get-CimInstance
    $usb = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Diskdrive | Where-Object { $_.InterfaceType -eq 'USB' } | 
           ForEach-Object {
               Get-CimInstance -Query ($wmiQuery1 -f $_.DeviceID.Replace('\','\\'))
           } | 
           ForEach-Object {
               Get-CimInstance -Query ($wmiQuery2 -f $_.DeviceID)
           } | Where-Object { $_.VolumeSerialNumber -eq $SerialNumber }

    if ($usb) { 
        # there's a LOT more info in this, but we only want the driveletter like 'H:'
        $usb.DeviceID 
    }
}
```

Use it like

```
$serial = '123XX456YY'  # enter the serialnumber here
$usbDrive = Get-UsbDriveLetter -SerialNumber 'FE948F5A'
if ($usbDrive) {
    robocopy "E:\Backup" "$usbDrive\Backup" /MIR
}
else {
    Write-Warning "USB drive with serialnumber '$serial' unknown.."
}
```

Comment: I have to check your implementation out, it's maybe more secure (and elegant) as it also limit the devices to the "USB" interface. My implementation seems to be shorter but maybe I'm overlooking something!

Answer (score 0):

I was maybe to fast to ask, but I found a solution while investigating the Get-WmiObject cmdlet.

```
$path = "E:\Backup"
$logfile = "D:\Logs\{0}_{1}.log" -f (Get-Item $PSCommandPath).BaseName, (Get-Date).tostring("yyyy-MM-dd")
$serialNumber = "12345678"
$systemDrives = "cde" # Protect C:, D: and E:

Start-Transcript -Path $logfile -Append

$drive = (Get-CimInstance -namespace root\cimv2 -class win32_volume -Filter "SerialNumber=$serialNumber").DriveLetter
"Found drive $drive with serial number: $serialNumber"  

if (!($drive -match "^[$systemDrives]:$")) {
    & robocopy $path $drive"\Backup" /MIR /R:0 /W:0 /NP /NDL
}

Stop-Transcript
```

I hope it can help someone else as well!